# How was the diversity between ethanol fermentation and lactic acid fermentation evolved?

Tags: microbiology, metabolism

Quite simply, some organisms metabolize glucose under anaerobic conditions via Glucose->(2) Pyruvic Acid->(2)Ethyl Alcohol. Some organisms, however, metabolize to lactic acid.

When did such a process (lactic acid) arise biochemically from its related (ethanol) fermentation, and how was it selected for? i.e What were the advantages?

<sub>Also, can someone create the [glycolysis](/questions/tagged/glycolysis) or [fermentation](/questions/tagged/fermentation) tag?</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is not clear from the physiology or biochemical information alone to determine what evolved from what. The intermediate pyruvate is always there, so **lactose dehydrogenase** (LDH) and **pyruvate decarboxylase** (PDC) could have each evolved anytime, and there are good reasons for both:

1. LDH: the reaction pyruvate + NADH/H+ = lactate + NAD+ + 25 kJ/mol is highly exergonic, i.e. produces heat
2. PDC: the reaction pyruvate = acetaldehyde + CO2 (and with ALD present) acetaldehyde + NADH/H+ = ethanol + NAD+ where ethanol is poisonous to other species

Add to it that there are organisms like *Sch. pombe* that have *both* enzymes, so can do both reactions, your questions should be rather:

**How has the enzyme LDH evolved?**

The enzyme is similar to malate dehydrogenase, both form a family. They belong to a group of enzymes that all have a **NAD(P) binding domain**, so it's not too far-fetched to state that LDH and MDH evolved from another enzyme with NAD(P) binding domain.

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/IEntry?ac=IPR016040

**How has the enzyme PDC evolved?**

> Protein sequences of pyruvate decarboxylase (PDC) derived from cloned
>   yeast (Saccharomyces cerevisiae) and bacterial (Zymomonas mobilis)
>   genes were compared with each other and with sequence databases.
>   Extensive sequence similarities were found between them and with two
>   others: cytochrome-linked pyruvate oxidase from Escherichia coli and
>   acetolactate synthase (ilvI in E. coli; ILV2 gene in S. cerevisiae).
>   All catalyse decarboxylation of pyruvate using thiamine pyrophosphate
>   (TPP) as cofactor. General overall similarity suggests common ancestry
>   for these enzymes.

cited from abstract of

Green, Jeremy. "Pyruvate decarboxylase is like acetolactate synthase (< i> ILV2) and not like the pyruvate dehydrogenase E1 subunit." FEBS letters 246.1 (1989): 1-5. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2651151?dopt=Abstract